# string literal pointer issue passing to nested functions

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, string-literals

So I have function that logs some data and writes that to a file and returns the path to the file as a string.

I then need to take that string and pass it to a function that parses the file and places the data in a structure

before the file can be parsed though, the string path needs to be "transformed" so each directory delimiter includes the escape character for the backslash. for this I pass the string to another function.

At a high level this seems like a very easy task, but I believe I am not passing the original return string correctly to the other functions, because when I check the output in the console after I  have transformed I receive the gibberish characters. below is a simplified example of what I am trying to do. I know my method of transformation is not the problem because if I take the lines of code that are in the nested transform function and put them in main(), everything works smooth, so it must be the way I am passing the pointer through the other functions and then trying to operate.

```
main(){
    char* filePath = logData();
    parseData(filePath);
}

int parseData(char* filePath){

    char* transformFile = transFormPath(filePath);

    //parse data from transformFile

    return 0;
}

char* transFormPath(char* filePath){      

    //transform filePath to newPath

    return newPath;

}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks!

Comment: 1. function definition should be `char* transformPath(char *filepath)' Similarly for `parsedata`.    2. There should be a return statement at the end of `parsedata`     3. You can then capture this new pointer in the main with `filepath = parsedata(filepath)`

Comment: what does tranformPath do?

Comment: @RishikeshRaje is there really a difference between char* filePath and char *filePath? the return statement for parseData is an integer, I didn't include this because it is not relevant to the issue I am having. thanks for the help!

Comment: The code is not standard compliant omitting the return type is discouraged since 27 years! Write standard C, not prehistoric K&R-C. Also `const` qualifying parameters helps the compiler to detect errors. And provide a [mcve].

Comment: @λuser transformPath, takes the filePath and steps through each character and if it finds a backslash, it replaces it with an escaped backslash, creating a new character array that represents the new filepath that will be returned and used for the parsing. this works, I just only get it to work when the statements are part of main, and not in the nested functions

Comment: How shall `transformPath` return a `char *`? it is `int`

Comment: @olaf fixed those issues, just kind of hacked it together, this is not my code obviously, just something I hacked together to give small example. thanks for the help

Comment: post the whole code, it's a pain to try to guess potential problems in code we can't see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, string operations cannot have a convenient interface, because of memory management. If a function receives a string, and converts it to another string, you should decide how to declare its interface.

The simplest interface is in-place (`strtok` uses it); you can use it only if the output is somehow smaller than input:

```
void func(char* input_and_output);
```

A more traditional interface is "output in pre-allocated buffer" (`sprintf` uses it); you can use it only if it's possible to calculate or somehow constrain the size of the output:

```
void func(const char* input, char* output);
```

Another idea is "allocate the output dynamically" (`asprintf` uses it); it doesn't have limitations but is harder to use:

```
char* func(const char* input);
```

Its disadvantage is the responsibility that it imposes on the caller - it must `free` the allocated string at some time in the future.

---

Let's use the third interface:

```
char* transFormPath(const char* filePath)
{
    char* newPath;
    newPath = malloc(100); // is 100 enough? no idea
    strcpy(newPath, "haha"); // just an example
    return newPath;
}

int main()
{
    ...
    char* filePath = "path";
    char* newPath = transFormPath(filePath);
    ...
    free(newPath);
}
```

If you decided to use this interface, your `transFormPath` function *should* allocate the string dynamically, and the caller *should* free the string at some time when it's not needed anymore. This is not trivial to accomplish - usually the "time when the string is not needed" is not easy to define, and if you change your code, the time when it's safe to call `free` can change without you realizing it. As a quick-and-dirty hack, you can write your code without freeing memory (i.e. introduce a memory leak on purpose).

---

Let's use the second interface:

```
void transFormPath(const char* filePath, char* newPath)
{
    // Here we assume newPath has enough space to hold the output
    strcpy(newPath, "haha"); // just an example
}

int main()
{
    ...
    char* filePath = "path";
    char* newPath = malloc(100); // is 100 enough? no idea
    transFormPath(filePath, newPath);
    ...
    free(newPath);
    ...
    char newPath2[100]; // is 100 enough? no idea
    transFormPath(filePath, newPath2);
}
```

A handy rule of thumb is "`malloc` and `free` should be called in the same function" - this interface makes it possible not to violate it.

Also, this interface makes it possible to use stack (automatic) memory allocation - if there is some limit on the size of the output, just allocate the maximum possible buffer on stack.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I appreciated the time you put into explaining this.